# Bash script for system-user, smb-user and netatalk-user with quoted parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parameter-passing

I wrote a little script that creates a system user account, a smb-account and an afp-account (Netatalk) in one step on a Debian server. Most things work pretty well except the **-c** parameter of the **useradd** command. It is quoted. I think this is the main problem. I did some research and I found how to keep quotes in args, but all my attempts resulted with the error code 2 and ended in the usage prompt of the **useradd** command.

I managed to invoke this line on the shell

```
useradd -m -d /home/username -p abcDEFghiJKLm -c "Full Name" -g users username
```

and what I get is the error code 2 and the usage-message of the **useradd** command.

```
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
       useradd -D
       <...>
```

This is my function to create an system user.

```
AddSystemUser() {
  echo "Adding system user"
  myArgs="-p $cryptPass"
  if [ "$fullName" != "" ]
  then
    myArgs="$myArgs -c \"$fullName\""
  fi
  if [ "$userGroup" != "" ]
  then
    myArgs="$myArgs -g $userGroup"
  fi
  if [ "$userGroups" != "" ]
  then
    myArgs="$myArgs -G $userGroups"
  fi

  doUserAdd="useradd -m -d /home/$userName $myArgs $userName"
  #echo $doUserAdd
  $doUserAdd
  myResultCode=$?
  if [ $myResultCode -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "Adding system user failed with error code $myResultCode"
    exit $(($myResultCode + 100))
  fi
}
```

As you see, I am adding the double-quotes at this place so I can use the syntax **-c Full\ Name** on the shell.

I also tried the method without adding the quotes in the script but typing them on the shell like **-c "'Full Name"'** with the same result: the usage message of **useradd**.

Can somebody please help me? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes don't nest; the escaped quotes you put in `myArgs` are treated as literal characters, not syntactic quotes that prevent word-splitting. This is what arrays were introduced for.

```
AddSystemUser() {
  echo "Adding system user"
  myArgs=( -p "$cryptPass" )
  if [ "$fullName" != "" ]; then
    myArgs+=( -c "$fullName" )
  fi
  if [ "$userGroup" != "" ]; then
    myArgs+=(-g "$userGroup")
  fi
  if [ "$userGroups" != "" ]; then
    myArgs+=( -G "$userGroups" )
  fi

  useradd -m -d "/home/$userName" "${myArgs[@]}" "$userName"
  myResultCode=$?
  if [ $myResultCode -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "Adding system user failed with error code $myResultCode"
    exit $(($myResultCode + 100))
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `eval` would work well for your situation:

```
: other code
eval useradd -m -d "/home/$userName" "$myArgs" "$userName"
myResultCode=$?
: the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day.

Both answers worked well. Thank you very much. Since it works now pretty well I will now post my whole script with the bugfix provided in this thread.

With this script you can add on linux an system-user, an samba-user and an afp-user in one step. It is tested on Debian 8.

There is just one flaw: With **afp** (**Netatalk**) it is not possible to create an user via shell without retyping your password. So in this script you will have to type the password four times.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# With this script one can create, change and delete a user for linux-system, Samba and Netatalk in one step.

fullName=""
userName=""
userGroup=""
userGroups=""
newPass1="X"
newPass2="Y"
cryptPass=""
addnewMode=false
changeMode=false
deleteMode=false

while getopts ':u:n:g:G:acd' OPTION
do
  case "$OPTION" in
    u) userName=$OPTARG;;
    n) fullName=$OPTARG;;
    g) userGroup=$OPTARG;;
    G) userGroups=$OPTARG;;
    a) addnewMode=true;;
    c) changeMode=true;;
    d) deleteMode=true;;
    *) echo "Unknown parameter"
  esac
done

ShowUsage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 -a|c|d -u username [-n full-user-name] [-g main-group] [-G group1,group2,..]"
}

AddNetatalkUser() {
  echo "Adding Netatalk user"
  (echo $newPass1; echo $newPass1 ) | afppasswd -f -a $userName
}

AddSambaUser() {
  echo "Adding Samba user"
  (echo $newPass1; echo $newPass1 ) | smbpasswd -s -a $userName
}

AddSystemUser() {
  echo "Adding system user"

  myArgs=( -p "$cryptPass" )
  if [ "$fullName" != "" ]
  then
    myArgs+=( -c "$fullName" )
  fi
  if [ "$userGroup" != "" ]
  then
    myArgs+=( -g "$userGroup" )
  fi
  if [ "$userGroups" != "" ]
  then
    myArgs+=( -G "$userGroups" )
  fi

  useradd -m -d "/home/$userName" "${myArgs[@]}" "$userName"
  myResultCode=$?
  if [ $myResultCode -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "Adding system user failed with error code $myResultCode"
    exit $(($myResultCode + 100))
  fi
}

AddUsers() {
  AddSystemUser
  AddSambaUser
  AddNetatalkUser
}

ChangeNetatalkUserPassword() {
  echo "Updating Netatalk user"
  (echo $newPass1; echo $newPass1 ) | afppasswd -n -a $userName
}

ChangeSambaUserPassword() {
  echo "Updating Samba user"
  (echo $newPass1; echo $newPass1 ) | smbpasswd -s -a $userName
}

ChangeSystemUserPassword() {
  echo "Updating system user"
  doChangePass="chpasswd $userName:$newPass1"
  #echo $doChangePass
  $doChangePass
  myResultCode=$?
  if [ $myResultCode -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "Changing password failed with error code $myResultCode"
    exit $(($myResultCode + 100))
  fi
}

ChangePasswords() {
  ChangeSystemUserPassword
  ChangeSambaUserPassword
  ChangeNetatalkUserPassword
}

CheckForRootPrivileges() {
  if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "You must have root privileges"
    exit 5
  fi
}

CheckIfNewUserDoesExist() {
  egrep "^$userName" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "User does not exist"
    exit 4
  fi
}

CheckIfNewUserDoesNotExist() {
  egrep "^$userName" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "User already exists"
    exit 6
  fi
}

CheckForUserExistance() {
  if [ $addnewMode == true ]
  then
    CheckIfNewUserDoesNotExist
  else
    CheckIfNewUserDoesExist
  fi
}

CheckParams() {
  paramCount=0
  if [ $addnewMode == true ]
  then
    ((paramCount++))
  fi
  if [ $changeMode == true ]
  then
    ((paramCount++))
  fi
  if [ $deleteMode == true ]
  then
    ((paramCount++))
  fi

  if [ "$userName" == "" ]
  then
    ShowUsage
    exit 1
  elif [ $paramCount -eq 0 ]
  then
    ShowUsage
    exit 2
  elif [ $paramCount -gt 1 ]
  then
    ShowUsage
    exit 3
  fi
}

DeleteNetatalkUser() {
  echo "Deleting Netatalk user"
  afppasswd -x $userName
}

DeleteSambaUser() {
  echo "Deleting Samba user"
  smbpasswd -x $userName
}

DeleteSystemUser() {
  echo "Deleting system user"
  doDeleteUser="userdel -r $userName"
  #echo $doDeleteUser
  $doDeleteUser
  myResultCode=$?
  if [ $myResultCode -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "Deleting user failed with error code $myResultCode"
    exit $(($myResultCode + 100))
  fi
}

DeleteUsers() {
  DeleteNetatalkUser
  DeleteSambaUser
  DeleteSystemUser
}

CheckPassword() {
  if [ $newPass1 != $newPass2 ]
  then
    echo "Password mismatch"
    exit 7
  fi
}

EncryptPassword() {
  cryptPass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $newPass1)
}

GetPassword() {
  read -r -s -p "Password:" newPass1
  echo
  read -r -s -p "Retype password:" newPass2
  echo
}

ProcessPasswordIfNeccessary() {
  if [ $deleteMode == false ]
  then
    GetPassword
    CheckPassword
    EncryptPassword
  fi
}

SyncUsers() {
  if [ $addnewMode == true ]
  then
    AddUsers
  elif [ $changeMode == true ]
  then
    ChangePasswords
  elif [ $deleteMode == true ]
  then
    DeleteUsers
  fi
}

CheckParams
CheckForRootPrivileges
CheckForUserExistance
ProcessPasswordIfNeccessary
SyncUsers

exit 0
```

I hope this script will help somebody.

Cheers.